# Rename array keys in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This is what i got...

```
 $shop = array( array( first_name => "john", 
                      last_name => "doe"
                    ));         
 foreach($shop as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
            $shop[$key][$key2] = $shop[$key]['newname'];
            unset($shop[$key][$key2]);
        }}

print_r($shop);
```

Which outputs

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )
```

Comment: Missing `[` before `'newname'`.

Comment: Sorry , that was an issue with posting the question, it was originally there, same issue

Comment: Also, your assignment line is backwards. Assignment goes from right to left: you're currently assigning a non-existent value to a pre-existent key.

Comment: @palladium You mean the `$shop[$key][$key2] = $shop[$key]['newname'];` line?

Comment: @Palladium Hmm that sort of worked, but it removes the 'first_name' element from the array, it now outputs `Array ( [0] => Array ( [newname] => doe ) )` could that be because you cant have two elements have the same key name?

Comment: Exactly. So you'll actually need to have the `newname` change dynamically to accommodate multiple elements.

Comment: @Palladium Perfect, add that as an answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the assignment line (line 6) around and make `newname` dynamic. So something like:

```
...foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
    $newname = 'new_' . $key2;
    $shop[$key][$newname] = $shop[$key][$key2];
    unset($shop[$key][$key2]);
}...
```

Comment: Hey, if you dont mind helping me one step further can you post the following code into http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and see why my values are getting erased id really appreciate it.. `$profileinfo = array( array( first_name => "john", 
                      last_name => "doe"
                    ));         

foreach($profileinfo as $key => $value) {
 foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {

  $newname = str_replace("_"," ",$key2);
  $newname = ucwords($newname);
  $profileinfo[$key][$newname] = $shop[$key][$key2];
  unset($profileinfo[$key][$key2]);
  }
}
print_r($profileinfo);
`

Comment: @JonahKatz Replace `$shop[$key][$key2]` with `$value2`. I haven't bothered looking into why it's doing that, but it should work with `$value2`.
EDIT: I know why now.  You used `$shop[$key][$key2]` even though your array was called `$profileinfo`.